# Springboot 2 app shuts down in openshift pod after startup..No errors. Works fine locally on windows

Tags: spring-boot

This is a Springboot 2.0.4 app. I can run it locally on my windows machine and it runs with no issues.
However when i deploy to an openshift pod, the app shuts down after start up with no errors.

2018-08-27 00:53:04.153 +0000 [main] [] [INFO ]o.s.b.w.e.tomcat.TomcatWebServer:87 - Tomcat started on port(s): 9010 (http) with context path '/mypath'
2018-08-27 00:53:04.160 +0000 [main] [] [INFO ]com.myApp.Application:87 - Started Application in 10.339 seconds (JVM running for 12.179)

### 2018-08-27 00:53:04.166 +0000 [main] [] [INFO ]com.myApp.Application:21 -

```
           Application 'my-app' is running! Access URLs:
           Local:                   http://localhost:9010
```

### External:              http://10.248.29.XX:9010

2018-08-27 00:53:38.508 +0000 [http-nio-9010-exec-2] [] [INFO ]o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet:87 - FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2018-08-27 00:53:38.538 +0000 [http-nio-9010-exec-2] [] [INFO ]o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet:87 - FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 28 ms
**2018-08-27 00:53:58.686 +0000 [Thread-5] [] [INFO ]o.s.b.w.s.c.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext:87 - Closing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@47d384ee: startup date [Mon Aug 27 00:52:55 UTC 2018]; root of context hierarchy**

This works fine locally. Any ideas how I can debug this further?

Comment: Is it something about the port 9010?? try with a different port?

Comment: I can try with a different port but I doubt that is the issue. If I deploy the same app with 1.5.4 spring-boot code, it works. However it shuts down with the 2.0.4 code.

Comment: Changed the port number but with no luck.

Comment: Can you please attach the full log then with log level debug?

Comment: Sure. Here is a snippet of the logs before the app shuts down.

Comment: I am not able to attach the entire log because of limit on number of characters-

Comment: ervlet.DispatcherServlet:87 - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2018-08-28 04:59:46.530 +0000 [http-nio-9010-exec-5] [] [DEBUG]o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet:87 - Successfully completed request
2018-08-28 04:59:46.842 +0000 [Thread-5] [] [INFO ]o.s.b.w.s.c.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext:87 - Closing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@31b7dea0: startup date [Tue Aug 28 04:58:38 UTC 2018]; root of context hierarchy

Comment: you cannot attach full, but you can past a major portion of it

Comment: Maybe it is my account, I can only paste in 550-600 chars of characters.  From the log file I don't see any exceptions. Just the Null ModelAndView returned to Dispatcher servlet and then the closing of the Application context with no errors.

Answer (score 0):

Verify how much time your application is taking to bring up in local, accordingly increase readinessProbe and livenessProbe - initialDelaySeconds andttimeoutSeconds in your openshift yml file